# Вывести количество комментариев к статьям внутри категории

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `table1`, в которой размещены категории и статьи, относящиеся к этим категориям. Здесь параметр `target` указывает на то, к какой категории относится статья.

Каждая статья может быть прокомментирована, поэтому, есть таблица `table2` со всеми комментариями к статьям, и в ней параметр `target` хранит `id` статьи из таблицы `table1`, к которой привязан комментарий.

Можно ли как-то в категории вывести общее количество комментариев ко всем статьям, привязанным к этой категории? То есть, каким-то образом нужно посчитать количество записей в `table2`, в которых `target`равен `id` статьи, привязанной к текущей категории. Честно говоря, совсем не представляю, как это делается.

Comment: Заведите отдельные поля в таблицах категорий и статей, где сохраняйте количество комментариев по категориям/статьям. Пересчет делайте в момент добавления/удаления комментариев (и статей).

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.target category, count(t2.id) count 
    from 
      table1 t1  
        join 
      table2 t2 
        on t1.id=t2.target 
  group by t1.target
```

Чтобы получить только одну категорию, поменяйте `group...` на

```
where t1.target=NumOfCategory
```

[**Демо на sqlfidlle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/141db/1)

Comment: Не "поменяйте", а "добавьте перед". Или убирать t1.target из полей запроса.

Comment: @Zufir Опыт лучший друг теории :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/141db/3

Comment: чё-то? для первой категории 3, для второй 1

Comment: Да, всё нормально. Экие мускуль вольности позволяет, прямо FoxPro6 вспомнился... Но вот при небольшом расширении условия - например, where t1.target in (1,2) - уже нужно. Так что лучше сразу приучить себя к нормальному написанию запросов

Comment: Пришла мысль: не эффективнее ли было бы добавить в таблицу с комментариями поле `category` и потом выполнять запрос попроще, учитывая только это поле? По скорости это, ведь, получится быстрее? А что насчет возможных проблем с таким подходом?

Comment: @nup, О_о О_о О_о

Comment: Быстрее, но будет дублирование информации. Если запросов много, смысл есть